# how this special python list generated?

Tags: python, list

I just faced to a question that confused me a lot. I meant to generate a list and for some reason I did something like:

```
mylist = [i for i in range(5), j for j in range(5)]
```

Then interpreter complained to me that that is invalid syntax at the position 'j' right before 'for'. So I define j before the list. Could anybody explain me why I did not need to define 'i' but 'j' ?

I expected to get something like:

```
[[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4]]
```

However, I got (I assign 2 to j in advance)

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I really confused here, could anyone tell me why I got this outcome?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to do is create *two nested lists*, so nest your comprehensions:

```
[[i for i in range(5)], [j for j in range(5)]]
```

or, since you are not doing *anything* with the expression, just:

```
[list(range(5)), list(range(5))]
```

In Python 2, even the `list()` call is redundant.

You did not share what your 'define `j` outside the list comprehension code' looked like, but do realize that a list comprehension supports *nested for loops*.

A list comprehension can be seen as a series of for loops and `if` statements, which, read from left to right are seen as nested statements:

```
[i for i in range(5) for j in range(5)]
```

should be read as:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        outputlist.append(i)
```

Judging from your output you did something like this instead:

```
[j for i in range(5)]
```

where `j` was set to `range(5)` on Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create two lists inside a list so:

```
list_ = [list(range(5)), list(range(5))]
print(list_) # [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

It's not a good idea to overwrite the 'list' buildin, so it's better to add a underscore to the `list` name or use another name.

Comment: underscore doesn't look right either.. how about `l` or `li`?

Comment: My bad. list is just a name that I wanna use to make the question clear. I've edited my question to erase the misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

To create what you wanted you can just do:

```
>>> [range(5)]*2
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

or, if you need the lists to be separate objects as pointed out by @Blckknght:

```
>>> [range(5), range(5)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: This may be dangerous, if you intend to modify the contents later on. That's because this has two references to the same inner list, and if you mutate one (say, by doing `li[0][0]=10`, you'll see the results in multiple places. If you're not going to write into the lists though, this could work just fine.